# I want to read text and replace parts that are surrounded by signals

Tags: c#, string

I have a chunk of text for example

```
string OriginalText = "Hello my name is <!name!> and I am <!age!> years old";
```

I'm struggling to write a function that I can enter this text into and it will return the same string except with the values surrounded by the Tags `"<!"` and `"!>"` to be replace with actual values. I have some code written but don't know how to progress any further.

```
if(OriginalText.Contains("<!")) //Checks if Change is necessary
{
     string[] Total = OriginalText.Split( 
       new Char[] { '<', '!' }, 
       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

     if(Total[1].Contains("!>")) //Checks if closing tag exists
     {
         string ExtTag = Total[1].Split( 
           new Char[] { '<', '!' }, 
           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0];

         ExtData.Add(Total[1].Split( 
           new Char[] { '<', '!' }, 
           StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)[0]);

         return Total[1];
     }
}
```

The desired output would be

```
"Hello my name is James and I am 21 years old"
```

I am currently getting this text from a database and so this functions purpose would be to read that text and input the correct information.

Edit: Figured out how to do it so I'm going to include it below however I'm writing this in a program called mattersphere so there will reference to functions that aren't standard c#, I will put comments next to them explain what they do.

```
private string ConvertCodeToExtData(string OriginalText) //Accepts text with the identifying symbols as placeholders
    {
        string[] OriginalWords = OriginalText.Split(' '); //Creates array of individual words
        string ConvertedText = string.Empty;
        int Index = 0;

        foreach(string OriginalWord in OriginalWords) //Go through each word in the array
        {
            if(OriginalWord.Substring(0,1).Equals("<") && OriginalWord.Substring(OriginalWord.Length-1 ,1).Equals(">")) //Checks if Change is necessary
            {
                string[] ExtDataCodeAndSymbols = OriginalWord.Substring(1, OriginalWord.Length-2).Split('.');   //Decided to create 4 different parts inbetween the <> tags it goes Symbol(e.g £, $, #) . area to look . field . symbol  //separates the Code Identifier and the ExtData and Code
                try
                {
                    foreach(ExtendedData ex in this.CurrentSession.CurrentFile.ExtendedData) //Search through All data connected to the file, Extended data is essentially all the data from the database that is specific to the current user
                    {
                        if(ex.Code.ToLower() == ExtDataCodeAndSymbols[1].ToLower())
                        {
                            OriginalWords[Index] = ExtDataCodeAndSymbols[0] + ex.GetExtendedData(ExtDataCodeAndSymbols[2]).ToString() + ExtDataCodeAndSymbols[3]; //Replace code with new data
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Extended Data Field " + ExtDataCodeAndSymbols[1] + "." + ExtDataCodeAndSymbols[2] + " Not found, please speak to your system administrator"); //Handles Error if Ext Data is not found
                }
            }
            Index++;
        }

        foreach(string Word in OriginalWords)
        {
            ConvertedText += Word + " "; //Adds all words into a single string and adds space
        }

        ConvertedText.Remove(ConvertedText.Length -1, 1); //Removes Last Space

        return ConvertedText;
    }
```

The text goes in "Hello my name is <.Person.name.> and I have <£.Account.Balance.> in my bank account" and comes out "Hello my name is James and I have £100 in my bank account"

The symbols are optional but the "." are necessary as they are used to split the strings early in the function

Comment: Why not use `String.Format` instead of creating your own system?

Comment: Your question would be a lot clearer if you could provide the contents of `OriginalText` and the desired output. Also, where do you get the "actual values", i.e. the fields you wish to insert into the text?

Comment: Also, as it is, your method will split on < and ! individually. Which means if there is a lone ! in the text, it will be splited too. It also  means that your first split removes the ! of the closing tag

Comment: Can you show example how you will use your function?

Comment: Have you been tasked with Rewriting the format() method as homework or something? Why not use the already existing and fully tested  logic rather than write your own?

Comment: Format would work if I knew what the text would be everytime but the text I will be using will have any number of characters within reason and will be coming from a database as well as there being anywhere from 0 to probably 10 variables surrounded by the "<!" "!>" tags

Comment: how do you know where to place the value `James`? is there a correspondence between `name` and something else?

Comment: @JackTyler So you are trying to build a simple templating engine if I understand well.

Comment: @Litelite Yes, on one part of the system a default template will be set of "Hello my name is <!name!> and I am <!age!> years old" and depending on the user that is running this task it will get their information and replace the variables in the text with the correct information.

Answer (score 4):

If you *have to* use `<!...!>` placeholders, I suggest *regular expressions*:

```
  using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...

  string OriginalText = "Hello my name is <!name!> and I am <!age!> years old";

  Dictionary<string, string> substitutes = 
    new Dictionary<string, string>(StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase) {
      { "name", "John" },
      { "age", "108"},
    };

  string result = Regex
    .Replace(OriginalText, 
             @"<!([A-Za-z0-9]+)!>", // let placeholder contain letter and digits
             match => substitutes[match.Groups[1].Value]);

  Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Outcome:

```
  Hello my name is John and I am 108 years old
```

Comment: Mind that numbers would not be allowed in placeholders (with that specific regex); for example "<!value1!>" would be impossible.

Comment: Nevermind the droids, this is the answer you are looking for. However i would mention that id wrap this code in a method and pass the dictionary/original text string through as parameters to make it fully dynamic.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you are stuck with that format, and assuming you know the list of fields ahead of time, you can compose a dictionary of replacement strings and, well, replace them.

```
        //Initialize fields dictionary
        var fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        fields.Add("name", "John");
        fields.Add("age", "18");

        //Replace each field if it is found
        string text = OriginalText;
        foreach (var key in fields.Keys)
        {
            string searchFor = "<!" + key + "!>";
            text = text.Replace(searchFor, fields[key]);
        }
```

If the values for the replacement fields come from a domain object, you could just iterate over the properties using reflection:

```
class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }

}

class Program
{
    const string OriginalText = "Hello my name is <!name!> and I am <!age!> years old";
    public static void Main()
    {
        var p = new Person();
        p.Age = 18;
        p.Name = "John";

        //Initialize fields dictionary
        var fields = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        foreach (var prop in typeof(Person).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance))
        {
            fields.Add(prop.Name, prop.GetValue(p).ToString());
        }

        ///etc....
```

And if you need the tag check to be case insensitive, you can use this instead of `String.Replace()`:

```
    string searchFor = @"\<\!" + key + @"\!\>";
    text = Regex.Replace(text, searchFor, fields[key], RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for this:

```
var str = string.Format("Hello my name is {0} and I am {1} years old", name, age);
```

Or, since C# 6, you can just use this:

```
var str = $"Hello my name is {name} and I am {age} years old";
```